# Issue when adding a text watermark to an image

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

When I run the following code, `mogirify` goes into this recursive loop and never seems to get out of it. I added some debug statement inside the `mini_magick` gem and printed out the logs - https://gist.github.com/kapso/5c4a4c7937c2e8f6667f

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("original.png")

image.combine_options do |cmd|
  cmd.gravity 'south'
  cmd.draw 'text 10,10 "whatever"'
  cmd.fill 'black'
end

image.write "output.jpg"
```

ImageMagick version:

```
$ mogrify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-5 Q16 x86_64 2014-07-25 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules
Delegates: bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png xml zlib
```

Comment: Don't make people go to a separate site just to see what is in a log. That wastes the time of people you want to help you and discourages answers. Instead, show only the pertinent part of the log in your question.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately the nature of the log was such (long) that I had to point to a separate link, without convoluting the actual question. But sure point noted.